# How to add proper validations to a signup and login form?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

```
    registerUser: (req, res, next) => {
        const { username, email, password } = req.body
        User.create(req.body, (err, createdUser) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            } else if (!username || !email || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Username, email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invaid email" })
            } else if (password.length < 6) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password should be of at least 6 characters" })
            }
            else {
                return res.status(200).json({ user: createdUser })
            }
        })
    },

    loginUser: (req, res, next) => {
        const { email, password } = req.body
        User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err)
            } else if (!user || !password) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
            } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
                return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
            } else if (!user) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
            } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
                return res.status(402).json({ error: "Incorrect password" })
            }

            // generate token here
            const token = auth.signToken(email)
            res.status(200).json({ user, token })
        })
    },
```

I want to check if the user is already there in the database, then the user will be able to log in. If not, then the message will be, "You are not registered".Right now, if I'm logging in with different email than the registered email, it's saying **email and password are must.**

All in all, I need to add proper validations in signup and login form.

```
    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { email, password } = this.state;

        const loginData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        }

        if (!email || !password) {
            return alert('Email and password are must.');
        }

        if (password.length < 6) {
            return alert('Password must contain 6 characters.');
        }

        if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return alert('Invalid email.');
        }

        this.props.dispatch(loginUser(loginData))
        this.props.history.push("/")
    }
```

In the frontend, I'm redirecting the user to the home page after login. Now the problem is, the user is redirecting no matter what the credentials are. Should I have to add validations here in frontend too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is, in the `loginUser`, before the condition reaches to `!user`, it will first enter into `!user || !password`. Thats why it keeps saying "Email and password are must."

Your logic would be like this:

- If user does not provide any email or password, you should return "Email and password are must" immediately, you do not wany to check in database anymore since, they provide nothing its meanless to do db search.
- If user do provide email and password, now you can do db check, if there is no match with the user's provided after searching through db, you just return "User not found" or as you said "You are not registered"

code:

```js
loginUser: (req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body
    if (!email || !password) {
        // user does not provide email or password, return immediately without db search
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "Email and password are must" })
    }
    User.findOne({ email }, (err, user) => {
        if (err) {
            return next(err)
        } else if (!validator.isEmail(email)) {
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Invalid email" })
        } else if (!user) {
            // user provide email and password however email deos not match any in db
            // this is equals to "You are not registered"
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "User not found" })
        } else if (!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
            return res.status(402).json({ error: "Incorrect password" })
        }

        // generate token here
        const token = auth.signToken(email)
        res.status(200).json({ user, token })
    })
},
```

Hope this is what you want.

Comment: I am actually not 100% sure with your problem, but I would suggest put the redirection code inside the login action, here is an exaple you could take a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-redux-registration-login-example?file=_actions%2Fuser.actions.js

Answer (score 0):

`(!user || !password)` means "if user is not found or password is not in the request body". If you want to specifically check if a user is not found you should have a `if(!user)` and act on that... Which you already do - lower down in the `else if` statement. But the first condition (`if(!user || !password)`) is a superset of the second (`if(!user )`), so you will never get to the second one. You should move this condition to be the first in the sequence.

Generally, I would rework your entire `if` statement to possibly nest some conditions inside others, e.g.

```
// user found:
if(user) {
    if(!user.confirmPassword(password)) {
        // user found but password is wrong
    }
} else {
    // user not found
}
```